# webpack task runner explorer - Unexpected token {

Tags: webpack, babeljs

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTA9H.png)I faced with next problem. I created project based on .net core 2.0 and angular 5 and used webpack for bundling. But when I run task runner and press "Run" I get such error :

```
["SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\YuriMihnovec\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AngularXAPI\AngularXAPI\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:30:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
Process terminated with code 1."]
```

What is the problem?
Thanks for help

[Here is my webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTA9H.png)

[Here is task runner explorer with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNoqI.png)

[Here is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqkJa.png)

Comment: Problem is solved! Thanks

Comment: How did you solve it? Can you please share your solution, it will be useful to other developers. You could write and answer to this question and check it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found this answer:

Be careful that even if you have installed Node 6 on your system, Visual Studio comes with its own copy of "web tools" and will by default prefer that to your global installation (and those tools are rather outdated).

You should change this by going to Tools > Options, search for External Web Tools then make sure your the order is:

local packages first;
global tools (PATH);
then VS bundled tools.

(See screenshot in link)

Source:  https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/799

The issue is that Visual Studio is running it's own older copy of Webpack. By adjusting the above settings, you tell VS to run global tools first, then fallback to VS if not found.